# Read mobile Numbers from Text File

Tags: java, regex

I have to read mobile numbers from the text file . I dont have the font type of text file so i am not able to read anything from it but the mobile numbers are coming fine. So i have to read those mobile numbers. I thing the best way is to use regular expression.

There are three type of formats of mobile numbers:-

1. 9929017726
2. 09896844430
3. 098968-72859

Please help me on this.

Comment: What is your question?  [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)  BTW - *"I dont have the font type of text file"*  Text files are not styled text - they have no 'font' and are displayed in the default font of whatever app. loads them.

Comment: you mention something about the fonts. what's the MIME type of the file? if it is plain text, you can just use BufferedReader.readline() to get the entire string then check the string length to determine the type of mobile number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex to extract the mobile numbers:

```
\\b(0?[0-9]{5}-?[0-9]{5})\\b
```

Comment: You created a better pattern than me, but I think you should use boundaries. Anyway +1.

Answer (score 2):

```
 \\b(?:\\d{10}|\\d{6}-?\\d{5})\\b
```

`\b` is a word boundary. It ensures that it doesn't match number partially, that means before and after the pattern must be a non word character (this includes also non digits)